# Why sensitive information Webform information exposed with jsonapi and custom access check?

Tags: webforms

I'm on D9.3.x with Webform 6.1.4.
Some sensitive information is exposed when adding a custom access check on webform submissions.

E.g. with no custom code, when GETting `jsonapi/webform_submission/my_webform` without right permissions the site returns:

```
    "jsonapi": {
        "version": "1.0",
        "meta": {
            "links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "http://jsonapi.org/format/1.0/"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "data": [],
    "meta": {
        "count": 0
    },
    "links": {
     [...]
    }
}
```

If I add a custom Webform handler with:

```
public function access(WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission, $operation, AccountInterface $account = NULL) {
    if($operation !== 'view' || $account === NULL) {
      return parent::access($webform_submission, $operation, $account);
    }

    $current_account = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('user')
      ->load($account->id());

    $webform_author = $webform_submission->getOwner();

    $webform_author_field= $webform_author->myfield->value;
    $current_account_field= $current_account->myfield->value;

    if($webform_author_field === $current_account_field) {
      return AccessResult::allowed();
    }

    return parent::access($webform_submission, $operation, $account);
  }
```

The same GET returns:

```
    "jsonapi": {
        "version": "1.0",
        "meta": {
            "links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "http://jsonapi.org/format/1.0/"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "data": [],
    "meta": {
        "count": 5,
        "omitted": {
            "detail": "Some resources have been omitted because of insufficient authorization.",
            "links": {
                "help": {
                    "href": "https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/json-api/filtering#filters-access-control"
                },
                "item--5EzsKk7": {
                    "href": "https://mysite/jsonapi/webform_submission/my_webform/5815d421-9ba1-4c2f-a1d3-00233261658f",
                    "meta": {
                        "rel": "item",
                        "detail": "The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."
                    }
                },
                "item--hsvvR7z": {
                    "href": "https://mysite/jsonapi/webform_submission/my_webform/66b5ae7c-24b0-46cd-9b7e-2e78969eae17",
                    "meta": {
                        "rel": "item",
                        "detail": "The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."
                    }
                },
              [...]
            }
        }
    },
    "links": {
[...]
    }
}
```

Thus exposing both the total of the submissions and their uuid.
Have you idea why it happens?

Edit: updated code and noticed one thing.
If the site has some submissions but the user has 0 which he can access with the "base" webform settings, the GET returns 0 in the "meta". Aka the custom code has no effect.

However, if the user has some submissions he could access to with the "base" settings and the custom `access()` function run the `AccessResult::forbidden();' then the "meta" in the GET is populated with the submissions the user could have access to.

Comment: Since the question is about code, we need to see the used code, or we cannot answer the question. Also, from the shown JSON, I do not see any exposed data; I just see an error message saying the user is not allowed to get the selected resource.

Comment: To make it clear: `$my_check = false; //some custom logic` is not enough code.

Comment: I updated the code, but I don't think it's relevant, I mean, there could be only ` return AccessResult::forbidden();` inside the `access` function to reproduce the point in my question. For exposed data I consider the count of submissions not visible and their uuid. Not a big deal, or so important, I'd agree, I'm more interested in why there is a behavior different from "base" settings.

Comment: How could users tell you what is wrong in the code you are using, if you do not show it? For example, you could forget to initialize a variable; users could not say that is what is wrong in the code, without seeing the code.